# Pattern to integrate million record if BULK option not available

Tags: integration, data-loader, design-patterns, architecture, solutions

This is in reference to Integration with a System having millions of records.

However, due to certain limitation we do not want BULK API needs to be implemented . Although there are other options like REST/SOAP integration with API been used to be BULKIFIED for maximum record process , But wanted to check is there something as in a design point that we can do to make this integration pattern best in performance and long time solution.

I have read the Integration Pattern Design (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_remote_process_invocation_state.htm) .   However unable to find something optimal for this scenario other than BULK API / ETL Tool using Bulk API.

Reason to avoid BULK API :

- Implementation Cost
- Alternative Solution to BULK API.

Data Volume is high however its less in case we upload million record in first Go and then opted for more than thousand but less than million.

Comment: The optimal solution for million-scale data loads _is_ the Bulk API. Why, specifically, are you not able to use it?

Comment: Because of System Limitation and Licensing issues , And as a keen to know the feasibility of implementing a methodology which works for large Data chunks without BULK API usage and doing with a pattern which justifies performance and scalability

Comment: What limitations? What licensing issues? Those constraints will also impact other potential solutions. Please [edit] your post to include detail of all the relevant constraints and data volume characteristics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be clear here: the Bulk API *is* available, and it is the optimal solution for single loads of 1 million+ records.

You haven't articulated any specific limitations around using the Bulk API, and I am skeptical about the suggestion that the implementation cost is higher. This makes me want to challenge the assertion that the Bulk API is off the table: what I'm reading is "I want to do X without using the tool specifically designed to do X." If that's not the case, you can edit the post to clarify exactly why the Bulk API is not suitable for your use case.

---

I've written two data loaders that use both the Bulk and REST APIs; while Bulk API 1.0 is a little bit more complex to implement than REST, the difference is not that substantial, and REST is massively slower and more API-call expensive. Further, Bulk API 2.0 is streamlined relative to 1.0. There are client libraries available for multiple languages.

The next best alternatives are probably [sObject Collections](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections.htm) endpoints and/or the SOAP API, at 200 records per request. Potentially, you could do a small amount of aggregation (up to 5 Collections requests) using the [Composite API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm).

Taking the sObject Collections API as a base case, you would be looking at 5,000 API calls to load 1 million records. The Bulk API 2.0 would require 3 API calls, plus any calls to monitor job status. Unless you write code in your integration to parallelize your API calls, sObject Collections will be *much* slower than the Bulk API. If you do write that code, your implementation will likely be rather more expensive than just using Bulk in the first place.

The situations I see where there's a clear case to *not* use the Bulk API are:

- If the integration is expected to be real time at high volume rather than a scheduled or punctuated load of high volume.
- If performance is completely irrelevant to you.

Otherwise, you should at least be seriously considering the Bulk API.

Comment: +1 Bulk api 2 is an efficient option often overlooked!